# Does filter() work in-place in python?

Tags: python

If I call filter() on a list, say:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x > 1, [1,2,3,4])
[2, 3, 4]
```

Is this:

a) creating a totally new list in memory with the results

or

b) is it just pop()-ing items from the existing list and returning the same list?

Comment: You could have falsified this hypothesis by [experiment](http://ideone.com/fo4QOw), or read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter).

Comment: Also, note that on Python 3, `filter` doesn't even return a list at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter returns a new list containing elements of the expression that satisfy the given conditions.  The original list is intact.  In your case, it doesn't really matter, because your list is an in-place constant -- but I assume that you have a more general application in mind.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter): it states that `filter` constructs a new iterable (list, tuple, ...).

Comment: One possible caveat: the elements of the new list are *references* to the same objects as in the original list, which could be significant in the case of mutable objects. Consider `a=[[1,2]]; b = filter(None, a); assert a[0] is b[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2

In Python2, `filter()` returns a *new* list object. The list passed into the function is unaffected. This can be observed using a very simple example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> filter(lambda element: element < 4, lst)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst # lst is unaffected
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

### Python 3

In Python3, `filter()` also does not affect the list passed in. However, it does not return a new *list* object. Rather, it returns a *filter* object:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> filter(lambda element: element < 4, lst)
<filter object at 0x7fb69fef1b00>
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

If you want a list object, you need to explicitly cast the return value of `filter()` to a list:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(filter(lambda element: element < 4, lst))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

In both cases though, your first hypothesis is correct. `filter()` does not do its work in place, it returns a new object.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x > 1, a))
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, I'll just leave this here.

```
>>> a = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> b = list(filter(lambda x: x > 1, a))
>>> id(a)
4510567816
>>> id(b)
4500803808
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

If you know python, you'll know `id` gives you a unique reference identifier. If they're not equal, it means they're different.

Answer (score 1):

Filter is acting on a iterable and creates a new interable.

Answer (score 0):

not really

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age) -> None:
        self.age = age

p1 = Person(1)
p2 = Person(2)
p3 = Person(3)
p4 = Person(4)
p5 = Person(5)
p6 = Person(6)

list1= [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5,  p6]
list2 = list(filter(lambda p : p.age > 3, list1))

list2[0].age = 100

print(p4.age)
print(p5.age)
print(p6.age)
```

output:

```
100
5
6
```